# is std:vector<char[30]> valid, or how to achieve this? (vector of fixed sized array?)

Tags: c++, stl, vector

I would like to have a notion of 2d arrays with one dimension fixed.

something like a growing list of char arrays of length 30.

Can i do something like vector
is that valid, or is there a way of achieving this

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: -1 for not trying it yourself first. Advice: first try and then if you face problem, then ask!

Comment: well.. i would have loved to, but at the moment, i only have access to internet, i am on road and i am trying to think of some solution.
Anyways, thanks for making it -1. But i really appreciate if you can provide the answer instead of typing so long.

Comment: Well, I'm going to assume that he wanted to know why it worked/didn't work and if it was a good idea in the first place :p but yeah, it could be asked better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No:  the type stored in a `vector` (or any other Standard Library container) must be both copyable and assignable.  An array is neither.

You can (and should) use `std::array` (or, if your implementation doesn't support that, `boost::array`).  The `array` class template provides a very lightweight container-like wrapper around an ordinary array; it can be used just like an ordinary array in most circumstances and has zero overhead (with a good implementation and with compiler optimizations turned on).

There is really no good reason to use an ordinary array (like `char[30]`) when you can use the `array` class template instead.

Answer (score 1):

A std::vector of std::array sounds like a better idea.