# push_back() in a 2d vector, what is the right syntax?

Tags: c++, stl, vector

I have defied a variable type as follows:

```
typedef unsigned int color[3];
```

I then created a vector of that type:

```
vector<color> RGB;
```

Now, say I want to push back a new element to this vector. What is the right syntax? My g++ won't let me do something like:

```
color temp = {255, 255, 255};
RGB.push_back(temp);
```

Which I thought would be a good syntax :( Any suggestions are very much appreciated

Comment: Why, what does g++ have to object?

Comment: The longest error message I've seen in my life. It's like a transcript of the holy bible or something. This is chapter 1 of the error message:
‘void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::construct(_Tp*, const _Tp&) [with _Tp = unsigned int [3], _Tp* = unsigned int (*)[3]]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/stl_vector.h:745:6:   instantiated from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = unsigned int [3], _Alloc = std::allocator<unsigned int [3]>, value_type = unsigned int [3]]’

Comment: part1c.cpp:66:24:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.5/ext/new_allocator.h:105:9: error: ISO C++ forbids initialization in array new

Comment: Duplicate of [is std:vector<char\[30\]> valid, or how to achieve this? (vector of fixed sized array?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902348/is-stdvectorchar30-valid-or-how-to-achieve-this-vector-of-fixed-sized-arr)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't use raw arrays as types for any of the standard containers.

The types must be assignable (they have either an implicit or explicit `operator =`) and constructable (they have either implicit or explicit default and copy constructors).

You could wrap your array type in a `struct` to allow use with the standard containers:

```
struct my_colour_array
{
    unsigned int colours[3];
};
```

In this case, the compiler will generate implicit operators and constructors. If you want different behaviour you can define your own.

For your use it might make sense to have an initialising constructor:

```
struct my_colour_array
{
    unsigned int colours[3];

// initialising constructor
    my_colour_array (unsigned int r, unsigned int g, unsigned int b)
    {
        this->colours[0] = r;
        this->colours[1] = g;
        this->colours[2] = b;
    }
};
```

Then you can setup your vector:

```
std::vector<my_colour_array> myvector;
// push data onto container via a temporary
myvector.push_back(my_colour_array(0,255,0));
// etc
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yep, that did it. G++ stopped crying now. Thanks.

Comment: "they have either implicit or explicit default and copy constructors"  A default constructor is _not_ required.  In the newly promulgated C++11, neither the copy constructor nor the copy assignment operator are required:  a move constructor and move assignment operator are sufficient (though the copy members may be required for some specific container operations, like copying a container).

Comment: @James: Yes, you're right wrt copy vs move semantics. Talking about `c++0x` and default constructors - the new allocator model has `construct` as a varardic template function, so a zero parameter version is available - I assume this would expose the default constructor, so that calls like `std::vector.resize(n)` (i.e. no object passed to copy/move from) would require a default constructor to be implemented. Maybe I have this wrong?

Comment: @James: In fact, I'm not sure I do agree with your 'move' only idea - again using `std::vector.resize(n, obj)` as an example (this time with copies from `obj`) - you can't 'move' from the same object more than once, so this operation only makes sense in terms of copy-construction. To access the full functionality of the standard containers I think you need copy semantics for some operations - can you confirm?

Comment: In C++03, a type is required to be copy constructable and copy assignable, regardless of whether you use an operation that requires copying (though, in C++03, pretty much everything requires copying).  In C++11, a type only needs to have the copy operations defined if you do something to the container that needs to make a copy.  Yes, `resize(n, x)` requires a copy constructor, and yes, `resize(n)` requires a default constructor, but there are lots of operations that require neither.

Answer (score 1):

You color type is pretty simple, so I would use another vector to define this type:

```
typedef vector<int> color;
vector<int> temp(3,0); // 3 ints with value 0
temp[0] = 255;
temp[1] = 255;
temp[2] = 255;
```

and then:

```
vector<color> RGB;
RGB.push_back(temp);
```